# Relation between users with messages

Tags: sql

I have a table of Users:

```
create table dbo.User
(
   Id int identity not null,
   Name nvarchar (400) null,
   // Other coluns as Login, Password, etc.
)

create table dbo.Role
(
   Id int identity not null,
   Name nvarchar (20) null
)

create table dbo.UserRole
(
   UserId int not null,
   RoleId int not null
)
```

Each user has one or more roles.

I need to relate users one to each other in periods of type.

For example, one professor to its students during 4 months in 2015.

And I also need to track messages between users.

One of my ideas would be the following:

```
create table dbo.UserToUser
(
   FirstUserId int not null,
   SecondUserId int not null,
   StartDate datetime not null,
   EndDate datetime not null
)
```

Being both FirstUserId and SecondUserId FK's of Users table.

```
create table dbo.Message
(
   ToId int not null,
   FromId int not null,
   Text nvarchar(max) not null,
   Created datetime not null
)
```

Being both ToId and FromId FK's of Users table.

Should this be done in another way?

Comment: These seem fine except I would expect UserToUser to have a "relationship type" category to indicate why the relationship exists.

Comment: Looks pretty good.  In UserToUser, the EndDate probably should be nullable (we don't know when the relationship will end for sure).  You may want to put a begin and end date on userrole to allow for roles to change over time.  i.e., a student may teach a class then go back to being just a student.

Answer (score 0):

This seems fine but you could be more generic with the relationships.  For example you might want to have more than 2 people in a relationship.  There are a number of ways to do this but I would do it like this:

```
Relationship
------------
ID
StartDate
EndDate
Category
... etc

RelationshipMembers
-------------------
RelationshipID
UserID
Order (may not be needed)
MembershipCategory (eg Professors and Students // messageFrom and messageTo)
```

Comment: In that case wouldn't the Start and End dates be in the RelationshipMembers?

Comment: @MiguelMoura - it can be both.  In relationship start and end would define the time span of the relationship (eg a semester's dates). In the members it would define the time span for that member being part of the relationship (a visiting professor's teaching dates or student's participation dates)